# BluemixでPythonから、JDBCでdashDBにConnectしたい

Tags: python

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype

jar = '/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/java/db2jcc4.jar' # location of the jdbc driver jar
args='-Djava.class.path=%s' % jar
jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
jpype.startJVM(jvm, args)
jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver', ['jdbc:db2://server:port/database','myusername','mypassword'])
```

でうまくいった人がいたのですが、Bluemix上のPythonから、dashDBにconnectするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

dashDB 接続に関して、Pythonは試したことがないのですが、以下のIBM DevOps Services に dashDB のサンプルがあります。見たところ、Python のサンプルもあるようです。

https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview

コードをみると import ibm_db とあるので、そのモジュールを使っているようですね。